# Is there any way to resctict telnet to communicate with C++ TCP server

Tags: networking, c++, telnet, tcp-ip

I have a TCP server developed in C++. Currently, it's allowing all connections in the XML bytes length protocol. Due to some security reasons, is there any way to restrict access from the client using telnet and only allow client connecting using the proper application, since Telnet is the application layer protocol and TCP is transported how can I restrict the application layer connection in TCP server.

Comment: That can only work if you provide a client that has this restriction incorporated. That client could then do a 2-way authentication (using a token server) where you refuse any connection not providing that token. Obscure sure :-)

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! This site is used for questions regarding the Ubuntu operating system. If your question is about programming, consider using [so] instead. If you find it more about networking, you can use [su].

Comment: Hi @Rinzwind Okay is there anything that can be done on firewall?

Comment: No.TCP is too simple for that. @raj answer is correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the connection over TLS and only accept connections from clients presenting certificates allowed by the server configuration. That of course requires implementing TLS in both server and client (which you should do anyway if you are concerned about security), but other than that, I don't see any reliable method of restricting user from connecting using any tool he/she wants.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will look for authentication model.
Can you help me with the telnet protocol. Is it works in UDP? 
If so then, how TCP application can block it at UDP.

Or is it can be handled at firewall?

Comment: Telnet is TCP protocol, and actually almost the simplest one possible, it's very close to "raw" TCP connection, so it's actually very hard to restrict someone from connecting via telnet.
As long as the connection is unencrypted, someone can sniff it and just replay any authentication credentials. So you either need to provide 2-factor authentication or encrypt the connection - that's why I suggested TLS. Or even both.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.